# Custom cell widget in QListView

Tags: qt, qt4, qlistwidget, qlistview, qlistwidgetitem

We have a custom widget that we want to use as item(cell) widget in QListView. And we don't want to use QListWidget. So is there any way to use our custom widget for a cell in QListView. The delegate seems to have a paint() method , but there is no method from which we can return the custom widget that we want to use for a cell. Can any one please help regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the custom widget do that can't be done with an item delegate?  Some more information would be useful.

Comment: `QAbstractItemDelegate::createEditor()` should return custom widget.

Comment: createEditor returns the widget that should be used while editing. Not the widget to be used for cell.

Comment: @G.M. We want to have one image view on the top that spans the width of cell. And some texts below that and some indicator view.

Comment: @G.M. We want to have one image view on the top that spans the width of cell. And some texts below that and some indicator view. So we are planning to design the widget in Qt Creator and return it in some delegate method.

Comment: @Arjuna So, it's kind of "display" widget? No user interaction (buttons, check-boxes, ...) ?

Comment: @Tomas -  Right now user interaction is not required , but might be required in future. How does user interaction  make a difference?

Comment: @Arjuna - If user interaction is not required, you can just simply call `QWidget::paintEvent()` right in the delegate's `paint()` method. For user interaction by mouse, you have to implement `QAbstractItemDelegate::editorEvent()` method. For interaction other than by mouse (keyboard) I am not sure.

Comment: @Arjuna - did you try the `void QAbstractItemView::​openPersistentEditor(const QModelIndex & index)` by the way?

Comment: paintEvent is protected method. So can't be called from outside. I don't want to open editor for the widget. I want to display custom widget in cells of list view.

Comment: @Arjuna - you're right, sorry. In order to invoke the `paintEvent()` of your widget, you have to use the `QCoreApplication::​sendEvent()`. But anyway, what's wrong with the "persistent editor" solution? It doesn't matter if you call it "editor" or not - it's just widget displayed inside the cell in any case.

Comment: Oh, I thought editor is some thing that opens when we want to edit a cell in a dialog. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149516/discussion-between-arjuna-and-tomas).